# What is the echo of function in ipython interactive mode?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I know the interactive model output is usually `__repr__` method return.

But in `IPython` or `jupyter` it dosen't.

for example：

```
In [1]: abs
Out[1]: <function abs(x, /)>

In [2]: repr(abs)
Out[2]: '<built-in function abs>'

In [3]: str(abs)
Out[3]: '<built-in function abs>'
```

In original python:

```
>>> abs
<built-in function abs>
```

How can I get the `<function abs(x, /)>` string in program?

Comment: I think that format is specific to the interpreter you're using (IPython?).

Comment: Please be a bit more precise what you mean by "how can I get <function abs (x, /)> string in the program"? What is the expected result/type and the intended use, preferable with an example.

Comment: .. what I mean that is confusing is the question "if the result is a function it self"

Comment: @deceze, thanks for point that out, it is an IPython feature. I have edit my question

Comment: @IODEV, I what to find a function `foo` which let `foo(abs)` returns "<function abs(x, /)>"

Comment: I still might misunderstand your need but why wouldn't **getattr(__builtins__, "abs")** work in this case?

Comment: @IODEV, I do not want to get function `abs` but the string describe it. the echo of a function in IPython includes more useful info than repr.

Comment: @PaleNeutron, my bad. I meant  `getattr(__builtins__, "abs").__repr__()`. I did some tests on a number of platforms and all returned the same. For details, have a look at the results in the answer below.

Comment: @PaleNeutron, what platform are you on where IPython or jupyter doesn't work? Secondly, what does it actually return?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the result of testing `repr()` on a number of platforms. All returns the same description: `<built-in function abs>`

Test code:

```
import sys, platform
print("repr:  ", getattr(__builtins__, "abs").__repr__()); \
print("os:    ", platform.system(), platform.release()); \
print("python:", sys.version, sys.version_info);
```

Result:

```
iPython online (rollapp.com)
----------------------------
repr:   <built-in function abs>
os:     Linux 4.15.0-137-generic
python: 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] sys.version_info(major=3, minor=5, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)


Interactive IPython 7.8.0 browser (pythonanywhere.com)
------------------------------------------------------
repr:   <built-in function abs>
os:     Linux 5.4.0-1029-aws
python: 3.8.0 (default, Nov 14 2019, 22:29:45)
        [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Jupyter online (jupyter.org)
----------------------------
repr:   <built-in function abs>
os:     Linux 4.19.150+
python: 3.n7.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov 17 2020, 23:42:15)
        [GCC 7.5.0] sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)


Jupyter online (cocalc.com)
---------------------------
repr:   <built-in function abs>
os:     Linux 5.4.0-1036-gcp
python: 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
        [GCC 9.3.0] sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)


macOS Catalina, python 2.7 (local)
----------------------------------
repr:   <built-in function abs>
os:     Darwin 19.6.0
python: 2.7.16 (default, Jun  5 2020, 22:59:21) 
        [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.29.20) (-macos10.15-objc- sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=16, releaselevel='final', serial=0)


macOS Catalina, python 3.8 (local)
----------------------------------
repr:   <built-in function abs>
os:     Darwin 19.6.0
python: 3.8.8 (default, Feb 26 2021, 23:59:43) 
        [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)] sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)


Python 3.4 online (onlinegdb.com)
---------------------------------
repr:   <built-in function abs>
os:     Linux 4.15.0-1044-gcp
python: 3.4.3 (default, Nov 12 2018, 22:25:49)
        [GCC 4.8.4] sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)


Python 3.8 online (repl.it)
---------------------------
repr:   <built-in function abs>
os:     Linux 5.4.0-1042-gcp
python: 3.8.9 (default, Apr  3 2021, 01:00:00) 
        [GCC 7.5.0] sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=9, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the built in attribute name with `getattr(__builtins__, "abs")`and the string representation using the ordinary `str()` ie:

```
>>> f = getattr(__builtins__, "abs")

>>> f
<built-in function abs>

>>> type(f)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>

>>> fstr = str(f)

>>> fstr
'<built-in function abs>'

>>> type(fstr)
<class 'str'>
```

or python < 3

```
getattr(__builtin__, "abs")
```

Comment: That does nothing that just `abs` and `str(abs)` doesn't do…

Comment: @deceze, it seems most platforms actually returns the exact same description. So far I've tested 18 different python versions including ipython and jupyter on MacOS,  Linux and Windows with the same result. Some of the results below.